# How to detect the playing state of the audio in UIWebView in iOS?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, audio, uiwebview

I have an `UIWebView` to load a [html](/questions/tagged/html) web link:http://m.y.qq.com in my iOS app. I don't know how to detect the playing state of the audio in UIWebView.

I just need to know whether the audio in `UIWebView` is playing or not in my iOS app, so that I can do something.

I have searched a lot from Stackoverflow and Google, but I can't find a satisfied answer. Can anyone give me some help?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if audio is playing with `isOtherAudioPlaying`

So in your `UIWebView` delegate methods you can use:

```
BOOL isOtherAudioPlaying = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] isOtherAudioPlaying];
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice,but it's not working.Acorrding to the words "isOtherAudioPlaying",it only can judge the other's state,not the current.

Answer (score 0):

`AVAudioSession` has a `sharedInstance` property which you can utilize in this instance. The property is a BOOL and can be updated upon multiple threads.

@tnylee's code is perfect.

Comment: Thank you for your advice,but it's not working.Acorrding to the words "isOtherAudioPlaying",it only can judge the other's state,not the current.