# How to tell if WKWebView is playing audio?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, webkit, wkwebview

I was curious if there was a way of telling if audio is coming from a specific WKWebView similar to the way you can find the tab playing audio in Chrome and Safari?

Comment: You can check the `UIWebView` solution, maybe it works for `WKWebView` too, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240647/how-to-detect-the-playing-state-of-the-audio-in-uiwebview-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

In the WKWebView's delegate, after webview loading finished, execute javascript that `addEventListener` to `audio` and `video` tag with event `play`, `pause`, `ended`. Then check the playback state for purpose.

Comment: Can you elaborate how, specifically for macos?

Comment: Can you explain how can do this with javascript please see and give me any suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview